# Why does an external hard drive suddenly become unallocated?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, partition-recovery

I got a brand new 8 TB external drive. I tested it in Windows 10 with SeaTools (both long generic and short generic tests passed).

Next day I connected the drive to a Windows 7 computer and it didn't show up. Drive management showed the drive as unallocated. After that, I could not access the drive from Windows 10 or Linux computers as well.

Since there was no data, I was not worried about recovering the partition. I simply initialized and formatted it. I am now able to access the drive from Windows 7, 10 and Linux.

What I want to know is why this happened. So that I can prevent it in the future when the drive has data.

Answer (score 0):

These things happen sometimes with no explanation.
The best guesses are either a sudden power fluctuation or a defective disk.

For power fluctuation, I would advise not to leave the disk powered-on
when unrequired. Protect costly equipment by getting a surge protector
or at best a battery backup/UPS.

For a suspicious disk, I would keep a careful eye on its [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)
indicators. A free products like [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) can help you with that
(but lots of other such products exist).